# Select rows having atleast 1 matching column value with a specific row

Tags: sql, mapreduce, hive

I've been trying to write a Hive query which allows me to select all rows that have atleast 1 matching specific column value with a single row i.e.

---

```
City     |   Mon  |  Tue  |  Wed  |  Thu  |  Fri  |  Sat  |  Sun
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Houston  |  Rain  |  Fog  |  Sun  |  Fog  |  Rain |  Sun  |  Sun
Denver   |  Sun   |  Sun  |  Sun  |  Sun  |  Fog  |  Sun  |  Sun
Seattle  |  Rain  |  Sun  |  Sun  |  Rain |  Rain |  Sun  |  Rain
Boston   |  Snow  |  Sun  |  Sun  |  Snow |  Snow |  Fog  |  Rain
Dallas   |  Sun   |  Sun  |  Sun  |  Sun  |  Sun  |  Rain |  Sun
StLouis  |  Rain  |  Sun  |  Fog  |  Rain |  Sun  |  Sun  |  Sun
```

Now I want to select all cities which had "Rain" on the same day as "Seattle"
So the results would be,

```
City     |   Mon  |  Tue  |  Wed  |  Thu  |  Fri  |  Sat  |  Sun
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Houston  |  Rain  |  Fog  |  Sun  |  Fog  |  Rain |  Sun  |  Sun
Seattle  |  Rain  |  Sun  |  Sun  |  Rain |  Rain |  Sun  |  Rain
Boston   |  Snow  |  Sun  |  Sun  |  Snow |  Snow |  Fog  |  Rain
StLouis  |  Rain  |  Sun  |  Fog  |  Rain |  Sun  |  Sun  |  Sun
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you join the `Seattle` row to each row then you can compare column by column to determine if you should keep each row in the result:

```
SELECT
    t.*
FROM
    table t
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM table WHERE City = 'Seattle') s
WHERE
    (s.Mon = 'Rain' AND t.Mon = 'Rain') OR
    (s.Tue = 'Rain' AND t.Tue = 'Rain') OR
    (s.Wed = 'Rain' AND t.Wed = 'Rain') OR
    (s.Thu = 'Rain' AND t.Thu = 'Rain') OR
    (s.Fri = 'Rain' AND t.Fri = 'Rain') OR
    (s.Sat = 'Rain' AND t.Sat = 'Rain') OR
    (s.Sun = 'Rain' AND t.Sun = 'Rain')
;
```